# Group list of strings by common substring

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a list of strings for example:

```clj
("2019_FOO_BAR.1_12"
 "2019_FOO_BAR.1_13"
 "2018_FOO_BAR.1_12"
 "2019_FOO_XYZ.1_14"
 "2017_FOO_BAR.1_14"
 "2017_FOO_XYZ.1_12"
 "2019_FOO_XYZ.1_13")
```

I want to group them by common substring after first underscore and before the dot.

In this example I have 2 unique substrings FOO_BAR and FOO_XYZ. But longer list may have N unique substrings.

I want the result to look like this:

```clj
(["2019_FOO_BAR.1_12" "2019_FOO_BAR.1_13" "2018_FOO_BAR.1_12" "2017_FOO_BAR.1_14"]
 ["2017_FOO_XYZ.1_12" "2019_FOO_XYZ.1_13" "2019_FOO_XYZ.1_14"])
```

So each substring is grouped in a separate list

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `group-by`

```clj
(def test-data '("2019_FOO_BAR.1_12"
                 "2019_FOO_BAR.1_13"
                 "2018_FOO_BAR.1_12"
                 "2019_FOO_XYZ.1_14"
                 "2017_FOO_BAR.1_14"
                 "2017_FOO_XYZ.1_12"
                 "2019_FOO_XYZ.1_13"))


(defn string-to-key [^String input-string]
  (let [first-spliter (.indexOf input-string "_" )
        second-spliter (.indexOf input-string "." )]
    (.subSequence input-string (+ 1 first-spliter) second-spliter)))
```

So you can get exactly what you are looking for with:

```clj
(vals (group-by string-to-key test-data))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking using group-by but wasn't sure about splitting function implementation.

Answer (score 4):

good candidate for regex:

```
user> (vals (group-by (partial re-find #"_.*?\.") data))

;; => (["2019_FOO_BAR.1_12"
;;      "2019_FOO_BAR.1_13"
;;      "2018_FOO_BAR.1_12"
;;      "2017_FOO_BAR.1_14"]
;;     ["2019_FOO_XYZ.1_14" "2017_FOO_XYZ.1_12" "2019_FOO_XYZ.1_13"])
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice and concise!

Comment: _Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems_ :)